# Problema para cambiar el texto del botón "Proceed to Checkout" en WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Estoy enfrentando un problema al intentar cambiar el texto del botón "Proceed to Checkout" en WooCommerce, ya que mi tema esta en español y es una plantilla de "GeneratePress" pero el boton del carrito de compras se quedo en ingles asi como el enlace de "Remove item". He intentado varias soluciones, incluyendo filtros de traducción, manipulación de DOM con JavaScript y otros métodos sugeridos en línea, pero ninguno ha tenido éxito.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy utilizando WordPress con WooCommerce y mi objetivo es cambiar el texto del botón de el enlace "Proceed to Checkout" a "Ir a Pagar" y "Remove item" por "Eliminar" en mi tienda en línea. He probado las siguientes soluciones como funciones dentro de el archivo functions.php de mi tema:

```
function custom_proceed_to_checkout_text() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('body').on('updated_checkout', function() {
      var buttonText = 'Ir a Pagar';
      $('.wp-block-woocommerce-proceed-to-checkout-block .wc-forward')
        .text(buttonText);
    });
  });
</script>
<?php
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'custom_proceed_to_checkout_text');
```

La anterior funcion usa jQuery, tambien la siguiente:

```
// Función para cambiar el texto del botón de checkout
function custom_proceed_to_checkout_text() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(document.body).on('updated_cart_totals', function () {
      var buttonText = 'Ir a Pagar';
      $(
        '.wp-block-woocommerce-proceed-to-checkout-block'
      ).html(
        '<a class="checkout-button button alt wc-forward" href="' + 
         wc_checkout_params.checkout_url + '">' + buttonText + 
        '</a>'
      );
    });
  });
</script>
<?php
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'custom_proceed_to_checkout_text');
```

Ninguna de las dos funcionó, luego intenté con la siguiente:

```
function custom_proceed_to_checkout_text() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(
      '.wp-block-woocommerce-proceed-to-checkout-block'
    ).find('.wc-forward').text('Ir a Pagar');
  });
</script>
<?php
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'custom_proceed_to_checkout_text');
```

y con esta otra:

```
function custom_translate_text(
  $translated, $text, $domain
) {
  if ($text === 'Proceed to checkout') {
    $translated = 'Ir a Pagar';
  }
  return $translated;
}
add_filter('gettext', 'custom_translate_text', 20, 3);
```

Luego esta con JavaScript:

```
function custom_proceed_to_checkout_text() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    // Espera a que se cargue el DOM
    var checkoutButton = document.querySelector(
      '.wp-block-woocommerce-proceed-to-checkout-block a.wc-block-components-button'
    );

    if (checkoutButton) {
      // Cambia el texto del botón
      checkoutButton.textContent = 'Ir a Pagar';
    }
  });
</script>
<?php
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'custom_proceed_to_checkout_text');
```

Agradecería mucho si alguien pudiera proporcionar una solución o sugerir un enfoque diferente para lograr este cambio de texto en el botón de checkout y en el enlace Remove item.

¡Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Busca en tu tema la carpeta woocommerce, dentro debe estar la plantilla que contiene ese boton, deber ser algo como checkout/miarchivo.php no recuerdo que nombres de la woocommerce pero debe ser algo como pay-form.php o parecido

Comment: Gracias Jefferzon, pero dentro de la estructura de carpetas del tema no hay ningun archivo que inicie con nombres parecidos.

Comment: Si no esta ahi lo que lo esta modificando es algun complemento, todos los actions tienen como parametro opcional la prioridad, por ejemplo, add_filter('gettext', 'custom_translate_text', 20, 3); en este action le estas pasando primero la funcion, luego el callback, luego la prioridad y por ultimo la cantidad de argumentos, intenta poner todos tus callbacks con prioridades altas, pruba desde lo mas bajo a lo mas alto y con suerte alguna tendra mas prioridad y se activara

Comment: La subi a 999 y aun asi no dejo hacer el cambio. me tiene pensando donde estara el error.

Comment: Ve a plugins/woocommerce y repite los mismos pasos que te dije, si aun asi no cambia entonces si o si es un plugin, la pregunta es cual, debe ser alguna de widgets, alguno que modifique woocommere o algo que tenga que ver con terminos graficos, es lo malo de los temas premium o gratuitos, tienen tantos plugins que no solo hacen lenta la web, si no agregan muchas funciones que aveces ni se usan

Comment: Si aun asi nada prueba a hacer testing, desactiva todos los plugins y deja solo el tema y woocommerce, si aun asi aparece entonces cambia el tema y verifica si sigue igual

Comment: La idea es descubrir si es un problema con el tema o con los plugins, asi estaras un paso mas cerca de la resolucion.

Comment: Gracias por la idea, voy a ir probando y te cuento si resulto.

Answer (score 1):

Se registró un incidente con mismo problema para el Tema "Neve Child" cuando se trabajaba de manera local en PC o computador con el Programa LocalWP Version 8.2.0+6554 en Windows 10 64bits. "Save" - "Remove item" y "Proceed to Checkout" permanecieron siempre en inglés a pesar de haber intentado lo mencionado originalmente por el usuario Nelcho, y entre otras cuestiones como agregar código a functions.php o bien del propio plugin woocommerce.php, se intentó con Plugin "Loco Translate" pero no dio frutos a pesar de tener todo actualizado (incluive mismo core de Wordpress, Themes, Plugins, y traducciones).

Otros datos de referencia: PHP versión 7.4 MySQL 8.0.16

De la manera que pudimos resolverlo es llevarlo al hosting, y ahí funcionó sin problemas.Loco Translate no fue necesario ni usarlo para cuando lo migramos al servidor web.

Aún no probamos la manera que propone OCHOA pero suena interesante.

Saludos :)

Answer (score 0):

No se tu, pero lo hice en 3 de mis clientes con un Snippet en mi plugin (para no usar ni **functions.php** ni Code Snippets o similares)

El código es el siguiente (probado en 3 webs)

```
function woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout() { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_checkout_url() ); ?>" class="checkout-button button alt wc-forward btn-v-dark px-4 py-3">
        <?php esc_html_e( 'Lo que tu quieras', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
    </a>
<?php
}
```

Resultado

[image: Boton 1]

O tambien

```
function woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout() { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_checkout_url() ); ?>" class="checkout-button button alt wc-forward btn-v-dark px-4 py-3">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-lock"></i>
        <?php esc_html_e( 'Lo que tu quieras con Icono', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
    </a>
<?php
}
```

Resultado

[image: Boton 2]

Ojo con algo. Las clases que le puse a mi botón (y tu debes poner a tu botón) son las que tiene ahora, esto para que conserve el estilo, ya que lo que se hace es que se cambia por completo el tag `<a>` y si no le pones clases o le pones unas diferentes el botón o pierde su estilo o cambia.

Los estilos también los puedes cambiar a tu gusto.

---

> Gracias Ochoa, voy a probarlo a ver si lo puedo lograr... una pregunta... el plugin que utilizaste para poner el snippet lo hiciste tu? o donde lo podria colocar yo para que me funcione correctamente?

El Plugin es mío, lo hice para todos mis códigos personalizados. Ya van varios que me preguntan sobre eso, veré que día de estos hago un post para enseñar de manera fácil y rápida como hacer un plugin propio en WP.

Y en efecto, el código lo debes poner ya sea en **functions.php** (nada recomendado) o en un plugin para tal fin como Code Snippets.

Otra cosa, el Plugin **Loco Translate** te puede ayudar a esta misión también. Solo debes buscar la cadena en cuestión "**Proced to Checkout**" y traducirla por "**Lo que tu quieras**" y funciona igual. Problema? Cuando se actualiza el Theme, pueda que debas volver hacer la traducción, pero que funciona funciona.

Pero usar muchos Plugins sabes que no es bueno y por eso yo mejor recomiendo usar código propio y si es en tu propio plugin, mejor !!!

Comment: Gracias Ochoa, voy a probarlo a ver si lo puedo lograr... una pregunta... el plugin que utilizaste para poner el snippet lo hiciste tu? o donde lo podria colocar yo para que me funcione correctamente?

Comment: Ya he modificado mi respuesta para responderte...